# FATAL EXCEPTION: main sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I cant understand this error, in my update command i have  10 fields to be updated but with this error `09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jpos/com.sys.Main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 11 is null`

it indicates that index 11 is null but the total column to be field at my table is 10.

```
09-17 17:18:25.203: W/dalvikvm(4929): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jpos/com.sys.Main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 11 is null
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 11 is null
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:237)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1636)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at com.jpos.classes.jposDbHelperHashMap.updateTableMunicipality(DbHelperHashMap.java:103)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at com.jpos.JPOSMain.UpdateTableMunicipalityCodes(JPOSMain.java:146)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at com.jpos.JPOSMain.onCreate(JPOSMain.java:115)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
09-17 17:18:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(4929):     ... 11 more
```

here is my update command

```
 private void UpdateTableMunicipalityCodes() {
        HashMap<String, String> queryValues =  new  HashMap<String, String>();

        queryValues.put("munc_id", "7");
        queryValues.put("rdo_code", "999" );
        queryValues.put("munc_code", "999");
        queryValues.put("munc_desc", "UPDATECOMMAND");
        queryValues.put("area_code", "999");
        queryValues.put("created_date", "2013-17-2013 06:02:29");
        queryValues.put("created_by", "SYSGENn");
        queryValues.put("last_modified_date", "2013-17-2013 07:02:09");
        queryValues.put("last_modified_by", "SYSGENn");
        queryValues.put("munc_status", "A");
        hashDbHelper.updateTableMunicipality(queryValues);

      }
```

to be pass here:

```
public void updateTableMunicipality(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) 
{ 
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("MUNC_ID", queryValues.get("munc_id"));
        values.put("RDO_CODE", queryValues.get("rdo_code"));
        values.put("MUNC_CODE", queryValues.get("munc_code"));
        values.put("MUNC_DESC", queryValues.get("munc_desc"));
        values.put("AREA_CODE", queryValues.get("area_code"));
        values.put("CREATED_DATE", queryValues.get("created_date"));
        values.put("CREATED_BY", queryValues.get("created_by"));
        values.put("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", queryValues.get("last_modified_date"));
        values.put("LAST_MODIFIED_BY", queryValues.get("last_modified_by"));
        values.put("MUNC_STATUS", queryValues.get("munc_status"));      
        database.update("tbl_municipality_codes", values, "MUNC_ID" + " = ?",     newString[] { queryValues.get("MUNC_ID") });
        System.out.println("Updated " + queryValues.get("munc_id"));        
      }
```

> Here is my create table query

```
    query ="CREATE TABLE [tbl_municipality_codes] (" +
              "[MUNC_ID] [INT(1000)] NOT NULL," +
              "[RDO_CODE] [VARCHAR(50)] NOT NULL," +
              "[MUNC_CODE] [VARCHAR(50)] NOT NULL, " +
              "[MUNC_DESC] [VARCHAR(100)] NOT NULL, "+
              "[AREA_CODE] VARCHAR, "+
              "[CREATED_DATE] DATETIME NOT NULL," +
              "[CREATED_BY] [VARCHAR(50)] NOT NULL, "+
             "[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] DATETIME," +
              "[LAST_MODIFIED_BY] [VARCHAR(50)],"+
              "[MUNC_STATUS] [VARCHAR(1)] NOT NULL,"+
              "CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_tbl_municipality_codes_1] PRIMARY KEY ([MUNC_ID]))";
```

> i think my error is in the constraint auto indexer from my table.. how can i fix it?

Comment: `queryValues.get("MUNC_ID")` should be `queryValues.get("munc_id")`

Comment: i assigned it to my table as all caps sir.. the "MUNC_ID" is my column name and the "munc_id" is my new value to be assigned.

Comment: What is 11th Column in your table,
Pls post Create statement of table.

Comment: hello thanks for informing me about my create table query.. in my sqlite browser it has auto index record counter.. and maybe there's an inconsistency of my filling fields because of auto generated counter of record..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read an entry from your `HashMap` that is not there, so you get `null`:

```java
queryValues.put("munc_id", "7");
...
database.update(..., newString[] { queryValues.get("MUNC_ID") });
```

As muratgu said, you have to use `queryValues.get("munc_id")`.